No module named 'qdrant_client' (FastAPI + langchain)
I am having trouble running my FastAPI project. I execute the following command: uvicorn main:ia --port 8000 --reload, and when it starts running, it throws the following error:

from qdrant_client import QdrantClient
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qdrant_client'

I have already tried different options, such as creating a virtual environment and installing the dependencies, and changing the Python version I’ve used 3.11 and 3.13 but the error persists. The funny thing is that I had this code in a plain Python file, and it worked correctly, but I decided to create a backend with FastAPI, and now it fails. I don’t know what else to try. I’ve also run the command pip show qdrant_client, and it does show information.


You have qdrant_client installed globally in your python 3.13. When you created your virtual environment, did you also install it in that environment?

Does this answer your question? See related answers here and here

Yes, I installed it globally and also in the virtual environment

I realized that even though I had the virtual environment activated, it was looking for packages in the global 3.11 environment. The solution was to run the project as follows:
python -m uvicorn main:ia --port 8000 --reload

